# Setting base class object to derived class object

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have four classes. Person, NaturalPerson (Inherits from Person), GroupFamilyMember(Inherits from NaturalPerson), QuotationHolder(Inherits from GroupFamilyMember).

They all share the same ID.

My problem is the following one:

There is a method that returns an existing NaturalPerson(stored in DB) object based on a document number. Then, I have to create a QuotationHolder, and I want that QuotationHolder object to contain the retrieved NaturalPerson object.

The issue, is that I can´t cast the object like this (I know the reason):

```
QuotationHolder quotationHolder = (QuotationHolder) naturalPerson;
```

I tried creating a new QuotationHolder object and setting its values with the naturalPerson´s object values using reflection.

But as I lose the reference to the retrieved object, when I want to save in cascade, NHibernate gives me the following exception:

> a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

I guess that its trying to save the object as a new one.

Just to consider:

The IDs are set using the HILO Algorithm.
The mappings cannot be changed, neither the classes.

Comment: I guess first thing you should try is yourNHSession.Evict(naturalPerson); before you save quotationHolder

Comment: Some told me I could use Merge command too. But I cannot access the Session. I have been provided with an Interface that allows only Save() and Delete(). What I wanted is to not lose the reference to the naturalPerson object and assign it to the quotationHolder one. But I guess this is not possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question, this is what you are trying to do:

```
class A {}
class SubA : A {}

A instance = new A();
instance = magic-convert-object-to-different-type<Sub>(instance);
```

Changing the class (type) of an existing object cannot be done in C#. NHibernate is designed to translate between the object model and a relational storage model, and therefore has no support for this either.

There are other possible models to handle when objects need to be perceived as changing classes, for instance the [State design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). Or maybe you should reconsider if this is really what you want at all - perhaps the additional data that the subclasses hold should be in "sibling-objects", that reference back to the basic person class.

It is also possible to use plain SQL to convert the data that represents the NaturalPerson into data that represents a QuotationHolder - when asked to load the converted data, NHibernate will now to instantiate a QuotationHolder instead.